# Can you explain the difference between "make action" and "take action"

Tags: meaning

Also, can you provide me with sample sentences using "make an action"?

Comment: Please show some research to indicate what you're looking for, and why what you've found doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that "make [an] action" does not exist as a phrase in English.

I would not say it myself.

Searching in the GloWbE corpus appears to give 50 instances. This is a small number, and 31 of those are "make an action movie/film/game" or "make an action plan", and most of the rest are instances of other meanings of "make" with "an action" as the object (for example "**make** an action on stage **look realistic**". I can find just four instances of "make an action" as a phrase in the corpus,

Comment: Interesting.  "to have the action", on the other hand, exists.

Comment: Also, "get some action" exists.

Comment: "Get some action" has a different meanin of "action". I don't know what "have the action" means.

Comment: I also have never heard the phrase "to have the action". It seems that Google has not either.